# Vue.js: How to convert an array to object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js

In Vue.js: How do I convert an array to an object? I wanted to get name value only "Willy" from the array.

Array data from LocalStorage:
`[{"id":"56b5","name":"Willy","email":"willy@test","password":"1234"}]`

I wanted it to be converted like this :
`{"id":"56b5","name":"Willy","email":"willy@test","password":"1234"}`

Please help.

to further use :

```
let user = localStorage.getItem('user-info');
this.name = JSON.parse(user).name;
```

and the result should be "Willy".

Comment: Don't save an array.  Just save the object.

Comment: I use db.json to store the data and It always return an array from the browser.

Comment: I think there is a lack of basic understanding of JavaScript Arrays here. If that's the case, check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-arrays/. Also, have you searched StackOverflow?

Comment: What is db.json? There could be a way to not end up with an array in localstorage if you need an object

Answer (score 0):

`[{"id":"56b5","name":"Willy","email":"willy@test","password":"1234"}]` is a single object inside an array. You can access it by getting the first object:

```
let user = localStorage.getItem('user-info');
this.name = JSON.parse(user)[0].name;
```

You may want to use optional chaining or similar pattern, if no data is in your storage:

```
let user = localStorage.getItem('user-info');
this.name = JSON.parse(user)?.[0]?.name;
// or
this.name = (JSON.parse(user) ?? [])[0]?.name;
```

You can also consider saving your `user-info` as the object instead of as an array (get the first object in the array before saving to local storage).

Answer (score 0):

localStorage can only store data in string type. so when saving objects to localStorage, you must convert them to string type, like this one `localStorage.setItem('user-info', JSON.stringify({}))`.

you should convert the value to object type when you get user-info`s data.

```js
const userInfo = JSON.parse('user-info')
```

your data is in an array with only one object. so you can directly access this object like this:

```js
const userInfo = JSON.parse('user-info') 
this.name = userInfo[0].name

or

const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-info'))[0]
this.name = userInfo.name
```

if you want to assign a value only when there is a value. you can do there

```js
const userInfo = JSON.parse('user-info') 
this.name = userInfo[0]?.name

or

const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-info'))[0]
this.name = userInfo?.name
```